# The data types varchar and varchar are incompatible in the modulo operator c# web service

Tags: c#, sql-server, varchar

I am creating a web app in c# in the app i am creating a webservice for finding a training number

```
[WebMethod]
[ScriptMethod(UseHttpGet = true)]
public void saverecd(string total, string date, string utrno, string modeofpayment, string transferdate,string trainer, string typeofadj)
{
    System.Globalization.CultureInfo enGB = new System.Globalization.CultureInfo("en-GB");
    DateTime dt = Convert.ToDateTime(date, enGB);
    Int64 paymentid = 0;
    string dt1 = dt.ToString("yyMMdd");
    string dt2 = dt1 + "0001";
    paymentid = Convert.ToInt64(dt2);
    SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("select max(paymentid)as paymentid from finalinstructoreexpense where paymentid like ''%' "+ paymentid +" '%''", con);
    con.Open();
    SqlDataReader dr = cmd.ExecuteReader();
    while (dr.Read())
    {
        paymentid = paymentid + 1;
    }
}
```

This is what I had done till now but when I run the web service I am getting the error

> System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException: The data types varchar and varchar
>   are incompatible in the modulo operator.
>
> at mvcerp2.newpayment.saverecd(String total, String date, String
>   utrno, String modeofpayment, String transferdate, String trainer,
>   String typeofadj) in Z:\mvcerp2\mvcerp2\newpayment.asmx.cs:line 88

and `SqlDataReader dr = cmd.ExecuteReader();` this is my line 88

how to get rid of this problem??

Comment: Basically, stop building SQL like that. Use parameterized SQL instead. Currently you have too many apostrophes, but if you used parameterized SQL you wouldn't have *any* apostrophes - you'd just have a parameter.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem is `''%' "+ paymentid +" '%''`.

First, you are using too many quotes, which ends the literal and instead thinks the `%` is an operator.

Second, you are prone to SQL injection. You can solve this easily by adding a parameter to your query. The last of your query should read like this:

```
where paymentid like '%' + @paymentid +'%'
```

Add this to your command:

```
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@paymentid", paymentid);
```

---

You can also combine the string client side, so that would mean you end up with this:

```
where paymentid like @paymentid
```

Add this to your command:

```
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@paymentid", "%" + paymentid + "%");
```

Comment: Doubt about this approach: `'%' + @paymentid +'%'`. I think you need create parameter with value = "%" + yourValue + "%". And then using it in query `WHERE column LIKE @parameter`

Comment: That is possible too. This will work. Trust me @Fabio

Comment: I did something like this

`SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("select max(paymentid)as paymentid from finalinstructoreexpense where paymentid like '%' @paymentid +'%'", con);
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@paymentid", paymentid);`

Comment: There is a `+` missing @MumbaiWadala: `'%' + @`